# MK Cloud - Limit Records - SQL Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I will need to send a quantity of emails each day and for this I'm trying to use LIMIT or ROWNUM function but none of this seems works in my SQL activity. Any suggestion how I can get only e.g 5 records of 50 in my SQL?

Comment: Can you paste your current query in here for troubleshooting?  I imagine that you tried a LIMIT statement at the end of your query already?  ie.  LIMIT 5;   Also, please tell the community what/why you're trying to achieve.

Comment: try like this   select top 5 from source DE name

Comment: I will need to send a quantity of the emails each day. So I will query all the data I have in DE but for each day I only want to send 5 emails from all I get.

`Select fields FROM DE_NAME LIMIT 5` > I receive error when I validate my query

I'm creating a automations to doing that and I'm using SQL Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @pkharries stated - you need to use select top 5, so something like this:

```
select top 5 
a.SubscriberKey,
a.EmailAddress
from _subscribers a
```